# Add specific plugins and config when using Birt with Maven

Tags: maven, birt

I've got a Maven jar project in which I use Birt in order to generate some PDF.

In order to use Birt engine, I've just added this dependency to my `<dependencies>`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I run my main class using [`mvn exec:java`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html).

My question is: when I was using the Birt runtime without Maven, I could add Birt plugins in the `plugins` dir and modify `plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts_4.4.2.v201410272105/fontsConfig.xml` in order to add specific `<font-paths><path ...`, how can I do this using this Maven environment?

I'm not sure also which path I must give to `org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.PlatformConfig.setBIRTHome(String)` or `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig.setEngineHome(String)` now.

I've tried to follow [the guide](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/reapi.php) and used `config.setEngineHome("absolute_path_to_a_4.4.2_osgi_birt_runtime")` but then I've got that stacktrace (inside a call to `factory.createReportEngine(config)`):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine$EngineExtensionManager.<init>(ReportEngine.java:822)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.<init>(ReportEngine.java:111)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory$1.run(ReportEngineFactory.java:18)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory$1.run(ReportEngineFactory.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory.createReportEngine(ReportEngineFactory.java:14)
```

It seems that [`Platform.getExtensionRegistry()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/4.4.2/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/impl/ReportEngine.java#822) returns `null`...

If I don't call `config.setEngineHome` nor `config.setBIRTHome`, then I've got `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ParameterValidationException: Required parameter myParam is not set.`, error that I didn't have before migrating to Maven (actually, my `rptdesign` use `myParam` from a linked library).

I've also posted my question to [Birt dev forums](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/39115-using-birt-with-maven/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use Birt 4.4.2 with this Maven configuration (due to the fact that the [pom.xml of the runtime](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/birt/runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/4.4.2/org.eclipse.birt.runtime-4.4.2.pom) is buggy and declares 2 different versions of those dependencies) :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.services</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.icu</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.services</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.v20140312-2051</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.icu</artifactId>
    <version>52.1.1.v201501240615</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, any Birt plugin can be added just like any classic Maven dependency (provided the fact that there is a correct `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` defining `Bundle-Name` & `Bundle-Version` properties).

Then you have to launch the [Birt engine in POJO mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37277570/535203): ***without calling*** [`EngineConfig.setEngineHome(engineHome)`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc.isv/engine/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/EngineConfig.html#setEngineHome(java.lang.String)).

Finally, for the font config, you can use either:

- [`EngineConfig.setFontConfig(pathToFontsConfigXmlAsUrl)`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc.isv/engine/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/EngineConfig.html#setFontConfig(java.net.URL)) (thanks for [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21705054/535203))
- [`FontFactory.register("path/to/myfont.ttf")`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/2.1.7/itext/src/core/com/lowagie/text/FontFactory.java#L348) (thanks for [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23058365/535203)) if you want to load a specific font from the classpath
- [`FontFactory.registerDirectory("/path/to/external/dir")`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/2.1.7/itext/src/core/com/lowagie/text/FontFactory.java#L367) if you want to declare an external directory of font to use (thanks for [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22227211/535203))

Here is an example of bootstrap code (based on [Birt website directives](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/reapi.php)):

```java
try{
    final EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig( );

    config.setLogConfig("c:/temp", Level.FINE);
    config.setFontConfig("c:/temp/fontsConfig.xml");

    Platform.startup( config );
    //If using RE API in Eclipse/RCP application this is not needed.
    IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
            .createFactoryObject( IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );
    IReportEngine engine = factory.createReportEngine( config );
    engine.changeLogLevel( Level.WARNING );
}catch( Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
// Run reports, etc.
...

// destroy the engine.
try
{
    engine.destroy();
    Platform.shutdown();
    //Bugzilla 351052
    RegistryProviderFactory.releaseDefault();
}catch ( EngineException e1 ){
    // Ignore
}
```